# I am having problems with setState

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm working on a simple login site and to navigate between Login and Sign up site I made a state called "aktivSide" meaning "activeSite" which is supposed to determine whether the login site or the sign up site will display.

Whenever I click on the "Registrer Bruker" (sign up) button, I get this error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setState')
```

```
import planB from "./plan_b.json"
import logo from './bilder/logo.png'
import './App.css';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faEyeSlash, faEye } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import React from 'react';



class App extends React.Component {
    //React
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            aktivSide: "tom"
        };


    }
    render() {
        //JavaScript


        return (
            //jsx (javascript og HTML)
            <>
                <div onLoad={() => this.setState({ aktivSide: <LoggInn /> })} className="App">
                    <title>SpeedType</title>
                    <header className="App-header">
                        <div id="topp">
                            <img id="logoen" width={300} src={logo}></img>
                        </div>
                        <button onClick={() => console.log(this.state.aktivSide)}>state</button>
                        {this.state.aktivSide}
                    </header>
                </div>
            </>
            
        )
        function RegistrerBruker() {

            return (
                <>
                    <h1>Registrer Bruker</h1>
                    <input type="text" placeholder='brukernavn' className='input_text'></input>
                    <div className='passord'>
                        <input type="password" placeholder='passord' className='input_text'></input>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon className='eye_icon' id='eye_icon1' />
                    </div>
                    <p id='passordTekst'>tom</p>
                    <div className='knapper'>
                        <button className='knapper_login'><p>Logg Inn</p></button>
                        <button className='knapper_login'><p>Registrer deg</p></button>
                    </div>
                </>
            )
        }
        function LoggInn() {
            //JavaScript
            return (
                //jsx
                <>
                    <h1>Logg inn</h1>
                    <input type="text" placeholder='brukernavn' className='input_text'></input>
                    <div className='passord'>
                        <input type="password" placeholder='passord' className='input_text'></input>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon className='eye_icon' id='eye_icon1' />
                    </div>
                    <p id='passordTekst'>tom</p>
                    <div className='knapper'>
                        <button className='knapper_login'><p>Logg Inn</p></button>
                        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ aktivSide: <RegistrerBruker /> })} className='knapper_login'><p>Registrer deg</p></button>
                    </div>
                </>
            )
        }
    }
}


export default App;
```

I've tried adding:

```
this.aktivSide.bind(this);
```

to the constructor, but nothing will display.

Comment: maybe binding issues

Comment: You should move the methods above `render()` instead and not within the render function then bind the methods in the constructor using `this.nameOfTheMethod.bind(this)`